# primitive data type in ptx

Tags: cuda, gpu, nvidia, ptx

```
__device__ __inline__ double ld_gbl_cg(const double *addr) {
          double return_value;
          asm("ld.global.cg.f64 %0, [%1];" : "=d"(return_value) : "l"(addr));
          return return_value;
        }
```

The above code is from here: 
[CUDA disable L1 cache only for one variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12553086/cuda-disable-l1-cache-only-for-one-variable)

According to the author, **"d"** means float, **"r"** means int.

I want to write a small piece of inline asm code, I want to know whats the symbol for rest of the primitive type variables (like unsigned short, unsigned long long, float-32, etc), I cannot find that from ptx isa.

I use letter "l" to represent unsigned long long, is that correct?

Answer (score 2):

You can find them [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/inline-ptx-assembly/index.html#constraints), but for the sake of completeness, the letters correspond to the underlying PTX register types:

```
"h" = .u16 reg
"r" = .u32 reg
"l" = .u64 reg
"f" = .f32 reg
"d" = .f64 reg
```

So an `unsigned long long` maps to "l" (for a 64 bit integer PTX register).

Comment: Thanks for this, and does int64 use the same symbol/reg type as uint64 here?

Comment: The constraint letter is the same between an `s64` register and a `u64` register, but the actual register type is different.  If you study the link that @talonmies gave, you'll notice immediately after the table excerpted above, there is an example that passes a parameter to an `s64` register using the `l` constraint letter.  Likewise you'll see examples where the `r` constraint letter is used to pass values to/from `s32` registers.